# One button triggers multiple labels

Tags: ios, swift

I am creating a calculator and want a single button to print multiple lines of text. Right now label 1 text is overridden when the button is clicked. I want to utilize label 2 3 and 4 to show more lines of similar texts as to label 1 when the button is clicked

[This image shows what i have setup. When i click add course, label 1 line is displayed with the correct information. What i want is the button to use label 2 3 and 4 to display more lines of text as i click add courses](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdyPP.png)

Comment: add your code please

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using multiple labels I would suggest using a UITextView and appending your new text as such:

```
myTextView.text += "\n You got 100%"
```

The `\n` inserts a newline character, making sure that your new text ends up on a new line.

---

An other way would be to add your labels to an Outlet Collection:

```
@IBOutlet var labelCollection: [UILabel]!
```

and then iterating over the labels in a for loop such as this:

```
for label in labelCollection {
    if label.text.characters.count == 0 {
         label.text = "You got 100%"
    }
}
```

This would check if label 1 is empty, if it is insert text there, if it is not empty, check label 2, and so on...

I personally would recommend the first approach since it is easier to set up and maintain.

Comment: With the first approach will i be able to assign ID to each new line of text in a way so that i can delete said line of text with a separate button?

Comment: @BestGiraffeNigeria In that case (please try to specify all your requirements in the original question next time) I would suggest using approach 1 but primarily storing the text in an Array, and then updating the text view every time you change the array's content.

Answer (score 0):

You could do this by using if and else if statements on the variables for example

```
if grade1 == nil {
Code for first label
} else if grade2 == nil {
Code for second label
}
```

And etc for the amount of labels you want to use.

Comment: well, you could, but it would quickly become unreadable if you have more grades to consider.  Have a look at `switch` statements - but @ast1's approach is better for this scenario

Comment: @Russell Very true, I would definitely recommend using ast1's answer too.